# Windows Azure iot hub telemetry message to push notification

Tags: azure, notifications, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to figure out the best approach for this scenario.

I have a pir sensor attached to a raspberry pi that is sending telemetry data to a windows azure iot hub.

I want to trigger a push notification when this telemetry data is received?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an Azure Web Job to consume the data coming to the IoT Hub and call a Notification Hub.

This would look like this :

[Raspberry Pi] -> [IoT Hub] -> [Web Jobs] -> [Notification Hubs]

Here are the pointers to the 3 key components

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/iot-hub/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/

You could use an Azure Function as a lighter alternative to a Web Jobs.

Comment: Thanks, I needed a push in the right direction. I'l see how I go.